# Cannot get json post from postman

Tags: php, postman

I am trying to send json body from in Postman [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daSIc.png) and I have simple php code get json body

```
<?php


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo($data);

echo $_REQUEST;
?>
```

When I sending json body from Postman it gives this things

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\Xampp\htdocs\Ass\index.php on line 7
>
> Array

So how can I get json values from php file?

Comment: try var_dump($data); instead of echo

Comment: The data shown in your image is not valid JSON.

Comment: @desoares Now it's showing `NULL `

Comment: Try to var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')), no json_decode

Comment: Your posted `Undefined offset: 0` error does not match your screenshot. To fix the error in your screenshot you need to `print_r($_RESQUEST);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. If you've seen my scrin on question the link on Postman was `https://localhost/Ass`. I changed it to `https://localhost/Ass/index.php` and I've got the json values

Answer (score 0):

The JSON content you are posting is not a valid JSON / PHP array.

There is an extra coma (,) after age's field.

Code

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($data);
```

Wrong content:

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "email":"john@email.com",
    "age":27,
}
```

Wrong content result:

```
NULL
```

Correct content:

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "email":"john@email.com",
    "age":27
}
```

Correct content result:

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "John"
  ["email"]=>
  string(14) "john@email.com"
  ["age"]=>
  int(27)
}
```

Comment: But it still gives a `NULL` result

Comment: @Kimfdirasdfasdf could you check my e.g.? https://imgur.com/a/HCoBRgI It is working with the data I wrote here.

Comment: You can try also change the Request Body Type to JSON (application/json) . See it here https://imgur.com/a/ApJubAt